# How to mock Yii2 component behavior in acceptance test?

Tags: selenium, testing, yii2

I want to test my application behavior using Selenium. But I want the `Yii::$app` component behavior can be mocked from the test runner?

Let's say I have a class

```
Foo extends \yii\base\Component {
     public function bar() {
         //return something
     }
}
```

And in the configuration I attach as `Yii::$app` component as `Yii::$app->foo`.

```
[
    'foo' => [
        'class' => 'Foo',
    ]
]
```

So the acceptance test works by running a web server and the test runner will run Selenium against the web server.

In the test runner I want to mock the `Yii::$app->foo->bar()` method so that it will return some string.

Usually when it comes from the database, we can mock by using Fixture. Test runner will fill the database using fixture that we set, and then the application component will read from that database.

How should I do this mock an arbitrary application component in the application run by the web server from the test runner?

Comment: There's two sides to this answer. One is that, in theory, you don't want your application to act differently for an acceptance test than it does in a real-world situation. That's why you run them against an instance of an application instead of a mock'd one. The less-popular answer, I'm sure, is that you'd want to indicate to the application (query param, etc) that it should behave a certain way given that its an acceptance test. Your component could check for that setting, and alter it's behavior. That said, if you're looking to mock functionality, you may actually want a unit test instead.